# System Error in Casio FX-9860GII C SDK add-in

Tags: c, calculator

There are no compiler errors and this is where I get the key presses:

```
while (handle_keys()) {
  Sleep(20);

  Bkey_GetKeyWait(key1, key2, KEYWAIT_HALTOFF_TIMEROFF, 0, 1, & unused);

  fill_old_squares();
  ball_update();
  angle += 1;
  ball_draw(WHITE);
  draw_stars();
  Bdisp_PutDisp_DD();
}
```

and this is where I handle the key presses:

```
int handle_keys() {
  if (key1 == 3 && key2 == 2) { //EXE key
    ball_jump();
  } else if (key1 == 4 && key2 == 8) { //EXIT key
    return FALSE;
  } else if (key1 == 4 && key2 == 9) { //MENU key
    return FALSE;
  }
  key1 = key2 = 0;
  return TRUE;
}
```

It says: TARGET=00000000 PC=00000001

Comment: What exactly is the error you saw?

Comment: @fluter Sorry, have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BKey_GetKeyWait function takes int references as the first 2 arguments.
If key1 and key2 are normal ints than you will need to change it from:

```
    Bkey_GetKeyWait(key1, key2, KEYWAIT_HALTOFF_TIMEROFF, 0, 1, & unused);
```

to:

```
   Bkey_GetKeyWait(&key1, &key2, KEYWAIT_HALTOFF_TIMEROFF, 0, 1, & unused);
```